# Scrapy POST Request with __VIEWSTATE not working javascript WebForm_PostBack

Tags: javascript, python, post, scrapy, viewstate

Trying to do a simple Scrapy python script that will scrape data from a site that uses the web form likes this:

`onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$DivMainCPH$ctl01$NRANearYouControl_2$imgbtn_Locate&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))"`

Let's say my site is example.com, below is my python spider that is not working but getting me back scraped HTML but not the response from the actual POST request.

There must be a way to get back the __VIEWSTATE that asp.net uses and capture this while resending back the POST request with the proper Form Data.  I'm using Chrome debugger to try and get exactly what the request was sending.

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request

class ShootSpider(Spider):
    name = "shoot"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://example.com"]

def parse(self, response):
    return Request("http://findtest.example.com/",
            callback=self.parse_2)

def parse_2(self, response):
   sel = Selector(response)
   self.log('A VIEW_STATE %s' % sel.xpath('//__VIEWSTATE').extract())
   self.log('A HEADER %s' % response.headers)
   self.log('A META %s' % response.meta)
   return [FormRequest(url="http://findtest.example.com/",
       formdata={'__EVENTTARGET': '', '__EVENTARGUMENT': '', '__VIEWSTATE': '',
            'ctl00%24ctl00%24ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolderDefault%24DivMainCPH%24ctl01%24NRANearYouControl_2%24LocationTextBox': 'richmond+VA',
            'ctl00%24ctl00%24ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolderDefault%24DivMainCPH%24ctl01%24NRANearYouControl_2%24ddlMiles': '200.1',
            'ctl00%24ctl00%24ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolderDefault%24DivMainCPH%24ctl01%24NRANearYouControl_2%24chkGrids%248': 'dg1',
            'ctl00%24ctl00%24ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolderDefault%24DivMainCPH%24ctl01%24NRANearYouControl_2%24imgbtn_Locate.x': '43',
            'ctl00%24ctl00%24ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolderDefault%24DivMainCPH%24ctl01%24NRANearYouControl_2%24imgbtn_Locate.y': '12'},
            callback=self.after_post)]

def after_post(self, response):
    self.log('A response from %s' % response.url)
    #self.log('Body %s' % response.body)
    filename = "Example_HTML_SCRAPE"
    open(filename, 'wb').write(response.body)
```

I'm getting back HTTP Status 200 - OK after ther crawl

Here are the command line crawl stats:

DEBUG: Crawled (200) http://findtest.example.com/> (referer: http://findtest.example.com/)

DEBUG: A response from http://findtest.example.com/

INFO: Closing spider (finished)

INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:

```
'downloader/request_bytes': 1451,
'downloader/request_count': 3,
'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 100405,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 3,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 24, 2, 42, 42, 766547),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 9,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'request_depth_max': 2,
 'response_received_count': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 24, 2, 42, 41, 381395)}
```

Comment: have you tried to use [FormRequest.from_response()](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.FormRequest.from_response)?

Comment: I did try this once but possibly didn't have the correct syntax.  Would the VIEWSTATE still need to be included in the formdata for the request?

Comment: You shouldn't have to add much to the FormRequest.from_response() return. You can always test it out in scrapy shell, and print out the response formdata

Comment: Turns out it doesn't like the blank __VIEWSTATE.  What I did to resolve it was run it in chrome and capture the viewstate it sent in the header and copy and pasted that giant string into the __VIEWSTATE property on the form and now it work!